# Как привязать к одной кнопке переключение двух картинок в Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

Не могу реализовать данное решение:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button myButton;
    private ImageView adolf;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
        myButton.setAllCaps(false);

        adolf = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        adolf.setImageResource(R.drawable.gray_100px);

        View.OnClickListener myClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switch (/*Вот! Здесь нужно как-то прописать содержимое экземпляра*/) {
                    case white_100px:
                        adolf.setImageResource(R.drawable.gray_100px);
                        break;
                    case gray_100px:
                        adolf.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_100px);
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
        myButton.setOnClickListener(myClick);
    }
}
```

Понимаю, что можно перекрыть методы equels и getHash, но в контексте Android, что-то не соображу.
Помогите начинающему Android'ологу!

Answer (score 1):

Заведите переменную типа `boolean flag = false` и напишите в `onClick` это

```
adolf.setImageResource(flag ? R.drawable.gray_100px : R.drawable.white_100px);
flag = !flag;
```

Answer (score 1):

switch тут не очень нужен:

```
boolean isWhite = false;

protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
    adolf = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    myButton.setAllCaps(false);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            toggleImage();
        }
    });
    updateImage();
}

private void toggleImage() {
    isWhite = !isWhite;
    updateImage();
}

private void updateImage() {
    if (isWhite) {
        adolf.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_100px);
    } else {
        adolf.setImageResource(R.drawable.gray_100px);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не можете получить ID ресурса назначенного в качестве картинки для `ImageView`.
Вам нужно поступить иначе - хранить в к-л переменной значение отталкиваясь от которого и назначать новую картинку. Например вы можете хранить ID в переменной как-то так:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button myButton;
    private ImageView adolf;

    private int imageId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
        myButton.setAllCaps(false);

        adolf = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        setImage(R.drawable.gray_100px);

        View.OnClickListener myClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                switch (imageId) {
                    case white_100px:
                        adolf.setImageResource(R.drawable.gray_100px);
                        break;
                    case gray_100px:
                        adolf.setImageResource(R.drawable.white_100px);
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
        myButton.setOnClickListener(myClick);
    }

    private void setImage(int id){
        adolf.setImageResource(id);
        imageId = id;
    }

}
```